# When I use apex:inputField (lookup type) on public site for Account, No records appears on the popup window. Where to look for?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup, account, record-access-level

When logged in When I'm logged into salesforce, it shows available records,
[image]

Following is From Public site.
When I click Look up button on Account field,

[image]

No records found due to one of the following:
    There are no records of this type
    You don't have permission to see any of the records
    Records do not fit the filter criteria set by your administrator

Also in Security settings, there is Enable External sharing, tried that too. Appreciate any help on where to look for enabling to view records in Accounts look up on Public site. Thanks.

Comment: Did you actually try to search? By default, a lookup field shows *recently used* items, so if that user hasn't recently used any items, nothing will appear by default.

Comment: Also, if you searched and got no result, try looking at the lookup filter.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox Tried Search., Search with * , but no luck.

Comment: @LanceShi Thanks. It doesn't appear for guest profile. No filters set.

Answer (score 0):

Found this,

I entered a Value in Search which is coming up within Salesforce search, then it's picking up the records.

But it did not show up any records when I clicked Go or when I tried searching with * . I hope this is being security measures for not providing external parties to view All records at public domain.

Comment: Notice the label of the list "recently viewed". This if none of been recently view nothing will be there until you search for something

Comment: @Eric Yeah! Thanks :) , the much you struggle there is a more chance of fortune..!